# Como baixar uma imagem da internet com C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Por exemplo, preciso baixar uma sequencia de imagens:

```
http://www.simepar.br/site/fragmentos/radar/simepar_24.gif
http://www.simepar.br/site/fragmentos/radar/simepar_23.gif
http://www.simepar.br/site/fragmentos/radar/simepar_22.gif
```

Como faria isso em C#? Teria com exibir essa imagem em uma [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: É windows-forms? ou web-forms? Qual é a tecnologia que está usando?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo a tag na pergunta deixa claro que é winforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que da maneira abaixo rola, e mais fácil

```
for (int i = 10; i <= 30; i++)
{
    string nomeArquivo = @"c:\download\arquivo_" + i + ".jpg";
    using(WebClient cliente = new WebClient())
    {
        cliente.DownloadFile("http://www.simepar.br/site/fragmentos/radar/simepar_" + i + ".gif", nomeArquivo);
    }

}
```

Tente algumas variações para ficar melhor adaptado ao que você deseja.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar WebClient para fazer isso:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead(imageUrl);
```

Dá uma olhada neste artigo que explica melhor http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24920/C-Image-Download

Abraço

Answer (score 2):

Se estiver falando de Windows Forms, então pode usar o método `Load` da PictireBox passando uma URL:

```
pictureBox1.Load("http://www.simepar.br/site/fragmentos/radar/simepar_24.gif");
```